# How to select nodes of a certain type, created by a certain user and which have reference field to a node equal a certain nid?

Tags: nodes

```
function mymodule_get_nodes_by_user_referencing_nid($type, $userid, $referncenid) {
    return node_load_multiple(array(), array('type' => $type, 'uid' => $userid, ??? => ???));
}
```

I need a function that lists nodes by following this logic: give me all nodes of a given type which are created by a given user and which have a node reference field referencing a given node id.

Any ideas about such function (in PHP, not in [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views))
)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code assumes you're using the entityreference module using field name "field_reference":

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node');
$query->propertyCondition('type', $type);
$query->propertyCondition('uid', $userid);
$query->fieldCondition('field_reference', 'target_id', $referenceid);
$result = $query->execute();

$nodes = array();
if (!empty($result['node'])) {
  $nodes = node_load_multiple(array_keys($result['node']));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The [`EntityFieldQuery`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7) class was made for just that:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', $type)
  ->properyCondition('uid', $user_id)
  ->fieldCondition('field_name_of_field', 'target_id', $nid);

$results = $query->execute();

if (!empty($results['node'])) {
  $nodes = node_load_multiple(array_keys($results['node']));
}
```

Note that `target_id` is the name of the column for an Entity Reference field; if you're using the References module it will be `nid` instead.